# Display Pop Up after the last word in a text

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Background** :

Onclick Text, we are displaying Pop Up....

**Issue** :

Pop up is displaying in some random place....

**Requirement** :

I want to display pop up after the completion of Full Text.... Please help me in dynamic way.....

[image]

Here is Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/q1nm3u20/

```js
var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 450,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 0,
            "layers": [{
                    "x": 57,
                    "y": 33,
                    "src": "2ccd95bae3f2a0c8249205ca5dfbed24_Montserrat-Bold.ttf",
                    "type": "text",
                    "size": 67,
                    "text": "First Line",
                    "name": "edit_good"
                },
                {

                    "x": 121,
                    "y": 99,
                    "src": "180ef82d12e3eee668a3f6b51ea444e9_Font972.otf",
                    "type": "text",
                    "size": 67,
                    "text": "Second line",
                    "name": "edit_good_1"
                }
            ],
        }, ],
        "width": 500,
        "name": "L1"
    }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // get the text from json

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
            if (name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1) {
                var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
            } else {
                var imageUrl1 = '';
            }
            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl1,
                maskImageUrl: 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";
            };
            counter++;
            // get the text

        }
        drawText(data);
    }

    json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

function drawText(layer) {

    if (layer.type === 'image') return;

    if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
        return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
    }

    if (layer.type === 'text') {
        const url = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + layer.src;

        if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
            fonts.push(url);
            $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
                "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
                "}");
        }

  // Below is POP UP Code
  
  
        $('.container').append(
           
            '<a onclick="document.getElementById(\'light\').style.display=\'block\';document.getElementById(\'fade\').style.display=\'block\'" ' +
  
   '<div class="textcontainer" contenteditable="true" ' +
            'style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' + 
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + 
            'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' + 
            '">' + layer.text + '</div></a>'  + 
   '<div id="light" class="white_content"> content <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById(\'light\').style.display=\'none\';document.getElementById(\'fade\').style.display=\'none\'">Close</a></div> <div>'    
   );

    }

}
// extempl code end 

// ignore below code

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        
        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };              
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
 background: gold;
  position: relative;
 
}

.white_content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 16px solid orange;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative;
}

.textcontainer{ position:absolute;  text-align:center; color:#FFF}

.textcontainer:hover {
     background: red;
     padding: 1px;
 border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Please let me know if you have any doubts....

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Getting the popup to appear directly after the clicked element is just a case of positioning the popup relative to the clicked text, with something like `left: 100%; top: 0%;`, but that might not work since you seemingly absolutely position everything. Is the JS loop creating the elements and positioning them with fixed pixel values part of some library you use? Since it feels very '90s and overcomplicated. Just asking to see if you are forced to have everything absolutely positioned or if that's something we can simplify in answers.

Comment: @Shilly Thanks for comment, i am displaying texts based on json file..... whatever values [ x : left, y : top ] present in json , i need to use same values for particular texts.... Thats the reason i used `absolute`.....  please let me know if you have any other doubts.... or did i understood your comment correctly ?

Comment: I want similar like [this link](https://www.greetingsisland.com/design/invitations/surrealism-balloons/201-14150) ,  if you click on texts in that link, than you will get to know.....

Comment: No that's what I needed to know. The solution will just be a bit more complicated that if you did not have to use absolute positioning, since now I have to go through the entire script to see how the absolute positions interact to know if we need to change the javascript so the top value in px of the popup has to change, or if we can do this with CSS only.

Comment: The issue is that the text you click on, namely the hyperlinks containing First Line and Second Line, are not the parent element of the popup. So you can do two things now. Either change the HTML structure so that you can position both the text and the popup to the same element. Or add javascript code to calculate the correct px values needed for the popup. I would advice the former.

Comment: @Shilly Thanks a lot for your valuable time & support, below answer working fine, also i will consider your suggestions......

Comment: Yeah, I'm glad someone was able to find the correct lines to change in the code to not break other stuff, was still working on that. PS, tell the person that is forcing you to code in this manner that using this kind of positioning system is needlessly complicating everything. We could write a solution in about 10 minutes time and 20-30 lines of code if only we did not have to use the x and y values for absolute positioning, which no longer makes any sense in these days of mobile devices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190899/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-shilly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position the pop-up to have `top = layer.y` which is the top offset of the `clicked` link. And to have `left = layer.width + layer.x`.

Besides the chaotic code which is extremely hard to read ( i won't get into that ) you append a div multiple times with the same ID which is a NONO in HTML.  Specifically you are appening `<div id="light"` for each layer. You are not allowed to have duplicate id's in HTML ( bad practice ) and in this specific case breaks the code.

So i added layer.name to the `light` id. So we will have unique ids ( as long as layers have different names ) .  `<div id="light'+layer.name+'"` . Also add it everywhere else where it's used.

Then in the appending code you should set the `top` property for the pop-up using `layer.y` . And then you can use the width of the clicked element to set the `left` property of the pop-up. You cannot do that as an inline style in the append ( like the case of top ) because the clicked element is appended the same time as the pop-up so it's undefined if we try to get it's width at the exact time of it's appending.

Anyway, long story short 
`top`: `layer.y` ( in the inline styles of the popup)
`document.getElementById('light'+layer.name).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 'px'` for the left positioning AFTER the appending.

Edit: added functionality to close the other pop-up when you open one pop-up

Just hide the `white_content` that doesn't have the id of the opened one. 
I added this line in the `a` tag `document.querySelector(\'.white_content:not(' + lightIdString + ')\').style.display=\'none\'` where

`const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
const lightIdString = '#' + lightId`

You can try to use just `lightId` and add `#` directly in the `querySelector()`

see here [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5rwacxz0/2/)

Or snippet below

```js
var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
  "layers": [{
    "x": 0,
    "height": 450,
    "layers": [{
      "x": 0,
      "layers": [{
          "x": 57,
          "y": 33,
          "src": "2ccd95bae3f2a0c8249205ca5dfbed24_Montserrat-Bold.ttf",
          "type": "text",
          "size": 67,
          "text": "First Line",
          "name": "edit_good"
        },
        {

          "x": 121,
          "y": 99,
          "src": "180ef82d12e3eee668a3f6b51ea444e9_Font972.otf",
          "type": "text",
          "size": 67,
          "text": "Second line",
          "name": "edit_good_1"
        }
      ],
    }, ],
    "width": 500,
    "name": "L1"
  }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  // get the text from json

  function getAllSrc(layers) {
    let arr = [];
    layers.forEach(layer => {
      if (layer.src) {
        arr.push({
          src: layer.src,
          x: layer.x,
          y: layer.y,
          name: layer.name
        });
      } else if (layer.layers) {
        let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
        if (newArr.length > 0) {
          newArr.forEach(({
            src,
            x,
            y,
            name
          }) => {
            arr.push({
              src,
              x: (layer.x + x),
              y: (layer.y + y),
              name: (name)
            });
          });
        }
      }
    });
    return arr;
  }

  function json(data)

  {
    var width = 0;
    var height = 0;

    let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

    let layer1 = data.layers;
    width = layer1[0].width;
    height = layer1[0].height;
    let counter = 0;
    let table = [];

    for (let {
        src,
        x,
        y,
        name
      } of arr) {
      $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
      if (name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1) {
        var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
      } else {
        var imageUrl1 = '';
      }
      var mask = $(".container").mask({
        imageUrl: imageUrl1,
        maskImageUrl: 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + src,
        onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

          img.css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": x + "px",
            "top": y + "px"
          });

        },
        id: counter
      });
      table.push(mask);
      fileup.onchange = function() {

        let mask2 = table[target];
        mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
        document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";
      };
      counter++;
      // get the text

    }
    drawText(data);
  }

  json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

function drawText(layer) {

  if (layer.type === 'image') return;

  if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
    return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
  }

  if (layer.type === 'text') {
    const url = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + layer.src;

    if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
      fonts.push(url);
      $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
        "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
        "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
        "}");
    }

    // Below is POP UP Code
    const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
    const lightIdString = '#' + lightId


    $('.container').append(

      '<a id ="' + layer.name + '" onclick="document.getElementById(\'' + lightId + '\').style.display=\'block\';document.querySelector(\'.white_content:not(' + lightIdString + ')\').style.display=\'none\';document.getElementById(\'fade\').style.display=\'block\'" ' +
      '<div class="textcontainer" contenteditable="true" ' +
      'style="' +
      'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
      'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
      'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
      '">' + layer.text + '</div></a>' +
      '<div id="light' + layer.name + '" class="white_content" style="' +
      'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
      'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + '"> content <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById(\'light' + layer.name + '\').style.display=\'none\';document.getElementById(\'fade\').style.display=\'none\'">Close</a></div> <div>'
    );

    document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 'px'
  }


}
// extempl code end 

// ignore below code

(function($) {
  var JQmasks = [];
  $.fn.mask = function(options) {
    // This is the easiest way to have default options.
    var settings = $.extend({
      // These are the defaults.
      maskImageUrl: undefined,
      imageUrl: undefined,
      scale: 1,
      id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
      x: 0, // image start position
      y: 0, // image start position
      onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
    }, options);


    var container = $(this);

    let prevX = 0,
      prevY = 0,
      draggable = false,
      img,
      canvas,
      context,
      image,
      timeout,
      initImage = false,
      startX = settings.x,
      startY = settings.y,
      div;


    container.updateStyle = function() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        context.beginPath();
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        image = new Image();
        image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
        image.onload = function() {
          canvas.width = image.width;
          canvas.height = image.height;
          context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
          div.css({
            "width": image.width,
            "height": image.height
          });
          resolve();
        };
      });
    };
  };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
  background: gold;
  position: relative;
}

.white_content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 16px solid orange;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
}

.masked-img {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.textcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF
}

.textcontainer:hover {
  background: red;
  padding: 1px;
  border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none">

<div class="container">

</div>
```

You get the error `Cannot read property 'style' of null",` because you don't have an element with id `fade`. You can sort that out.

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine, can you please help me to hide the `1st pop up` once we click on 2nd text something like [here](https://www.greetingsisland.com/design/invitations/surrealism-balloons/201-14150).... as displaying two pop ups may confuse users.....

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5rwacxz0/2/ Just hide the `white_content` that doesn't have the id of the opened one. I added this line in the `a` tag `document.querySelector(\'.white_content:not(' + lightIdString + ')\').style.display=\'none\'` where ` const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
    const lightIdString = '#' + lightId` You can try to use just `lightId` and add `#` directly in the `querySelector()` See here https://jsfiddle.net/5rwacxz0/2/

Comment: No problem. Glad i could help\

Comment: Thanks again, its working fine for 2 lines, but when i tried for more lines it did't worked for me, so i posted [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412545/close-the-other-pop-up-when-we-open-one-pop-up/)